# Copy all charts from excel into an existing powerpoint

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have 35 excel files that each have 50 charts in them (all on the same sheet). I need to copy each of the charts over to a powerpoint file, which is already made with specific formatting and labels for positioning of the charts. How would I go about writing a script that will reference all of the charts in the respective excel file and then send them to the powerpoint at specific locations and page numbers of the powerpoint, some being differently sized?

I am assuming a forloop for referencing each of the charts, then an explicit code for each chart once numbered in the forloop to resize and place at specifc locations in the powerpoint.

Once I get an idea of how to reference each of the charts, resize and then place at specific point in the ppt slide, I can automate the entire thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that StackOverflow is not a coding service. Bearing that in mind this is how I would go about it:
 1. Put placeholders in the PowerPoint. These placeholders contain a unique identifier of each chart object (e.g. Workbook1.Sheet1.Chart1). I would make sure they are sized as your chart would be in the end (width & height) and that they are invisible. I would use rectangles with 100% transparency, and use the [Alt Text property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shape.alternativetext).
 2. Write a sub that deletes all charts but keeps all placeholders in your PowerPoint file.
 3. Write a function that retrieves the charts per placeholder.
 4. Write a sub that copies the chart object and pastes it as a picture.
 5. Write a sub that loops through all placeholders in your file, gets and pastes all charts.

Comment: Thanks man. Just needed an idea of the process and functions to use.

Comment: @hkml Let us know how it goes. If you can post your code as solution in the end that will benefit the community.

Comment: Roger. Will take me some time to complete, but will post when done. Thanks.